# Listen a signal from a processus by pid

Tags: c, signals, handle

Consider two processes, A and B, with standard input and output streams connected to each other via pipes to form a closed loop.  Suppose that, as a result of an [exec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec), the two processes are not directly aware of their relationship with each other.

If B is abruptly terminated (e.g. by sending it a `SIGKILL`), how can A know that B died? Or at least, make A died too

Quick view of the situation, where Cmd is A and B Client :
[image]

Comment: I don't understand "A exec himself with another program."  Is A execing the same binary it is already running?  Is it execing a different binary?  Is it forking first?

Comment: What is the nature of the piped dialog between the processes?

Comment: You mean `pipe`(2) pipes, right?  Not FIFOs (aka "named pipes") recorded in the file system?

Comment: (1,2) I can't use the pipe to pass the information, because A can execing any programs you wan't... (3) Yes I mean pipe(2)

Comment: But I actually wonder if I can attach A to B as a child, and handle him with that property

Comment: I'm still not following the situation you're trying to describe.  Note in particular that if thread A successfully execs, then its entire process image (including any other threads) is replaced with a new one.  In what sense do you expect the new image to find any kind of notification about the state of B meaningful?

Comment: The standard input of B is sent to A and the ouput of A is sent to B (throught the pipes)

Comment: I have reworded the question as I think you mean based on your comments.  Feel free to revert or edit further if I have not adequately captured it.

Comment: thanks to you.
Do you know if there's a function like change_parent(pid_t pid) that set the calling process parent on the pid ?

Comment: No, a process cannot be manually reparented.  If a child process outlives its parent, however, then process 1 becomes its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you, the only thing you have to work with is the pipes.  Nothing else that might help you carries across an exec, especially if we suppose that the program running in process **A** is not specifically designed for this interaction.  Let us therefore consider what you can do with the pipes.

When **B** terminates, for whatever reason, all its open file handles are closed.  That includes its handles on the pipe ends.

If **A** thereafter attempts to write to its own `stdout`, and the read end is not open in any process,<sup>*</sup> then A will receive a `SIGPIPE`, as @indianant observed.  The default disposition for that signal is to terminate the process, so **A** will then die too unless it has changed the disposition for that signal.  Whether **A** changes the disposition of `SIGPIPE` is out of your control unless the program running in **A** is one you've provided.

But perhaps **A** will be blocked reading from its standard input when **B** terminates.  Supposing that **B** was the only process holding the write end of that pipe open, **A** will then see EOF on its standard input.  This will not automatically cause **A** to terminate, but it can respond appropriately to that event, which might cause it to terminate naturally.  Additionally, **A** may first receive data written by **B** before its termination; if **A** responds by trying to write to its standard output, then the previous paragraph applies.

None of that applies, however, unless **A** is actually performing I/O on its standard streams.  If you're looking for some kind of asynchronous notification, then you probably need to make that the responsibility of a third process.  It would be easiest for that purpose to give **A** and **B** a common parent process, possibly one dedicated to the purpose.  The parent will be notified via a `SIGCHLD` or by returning from a `wait()` or `waitpid()` when one of its children dies; it could then take appropriate action such as killing the other child.  Note that this does not work for **A** being the parent of **B**, or `vise versa`, because signal handlers are not carried over an exec, except possibly `SIG_IGN` for `SIGCHLD`.

<sup>*</sup>In particular, make sure the read end is not open in *A* by closing it before the exec.

Comment: But how can A saw EOF if he exec ? Should I do a thread which have the pid of A, and make him try to know when B is dead by checking on the existence of the pipes ?

Unfortunatly, i can't do your last proposition... I have to follow this architecture for a school project...

Comment: @ThomasPetillot as I said, if you've only the pipes to rely upon, then you can only detect the other process's state when you are doing I/O.  And you can only do it *in the normal course* of your program's I/O, because otherwise you will interfere with the program's behavior.

Comment: So I have make A sending his pid on the output, and B catch it so it can kill him when he want. thanks for your help

Comment: @ThomasPetillot, but if **A** is the parent of **B**, *and you have full control of the implementation of the program execed in **A***, then you could make that program register a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`.  That handler will be notified when any child process dies, and it can take appropriate action.

Comment: A isn't, I add a quick view of what I am doing

Comment: @ThomasPetillot, for **A** and **B** to be connected by pipes, with **A**  not being the parent of **B**, the two must have a shared ancestor somewhere that created those pipes.  In that ancestor -- ideally a common parent -- is where the functionality I described in my third alternative could live.

Comment: @ThomasPetillot, not also that relying on **B** to kill **A** will not be effective in all cases.  In particular, it cannot be effective when **B** is killed by a `SIGKILL`, as no handler can be installed for that signal.

Answer (score 1):

"A" receives SIGPIPE signal when it writes to pipe where consumer is killed.

You can register handler for SIGPIPE and handle it gracefully.

Comment: That would be a possibility if process A can be relied upon to try to write to the pipe after B terminates.  Whether that indeed describes the OP's scenario is impossible to determine based on the information currently available.

Comment: Doesn't works, because if A have a block processing when B died, he will never know...